# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are convergent and $a_n, b_n > 0$ then so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max\lbrace a_n, b_n\rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

The question given is that in the title;

> If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are convergent and $a_n, b_n > 0$ then so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max\lbrace a_n, b_n\rbrace.$

The answer given in my textbook is as follows;

> Certainly $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n + b_n)$ is convergent. Since $\max\lbrace a_n, b_n\rbrace < a_n + b_n$, it follows from the comparison test that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max\lbrace a_n, b_n\rbrace$ is convergent.

I understand this solution but I wrote something along the lines of

> Since both series are convergent we can simply say that $$A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ \ \text{and} \ \ B = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n.$$
>   Then $\max\lbrace a_n, b_n \rbrace = \frac{1}{2}(a_n + b_n + \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert)$ and so 
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \max\lbrace a_n, b_n\rbrace &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n + b_n + \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert\\
> &= \frac{1}{2}(A + B + \lvert A - B\rvert)
> \end{align}

Is this valid too?

Comment: $\sum_n |a_n - b_n|$ does converge, but not in general  to $|A-B|$.  However, you still have to prove that it converges (which is not really easier than the original question).

Comment: Actually I've just seen a way to go from my solution to the book's solution via the triangle inequality and a comparison, I believe.

Comment: @JohnDawkins You hint is exactly the OP's textbook proof. The question is all about what the OP did, not what other options they had...

Answer (score 1):

It won't be true in general that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n-b_n|=|A-B|$. For instance, suppose that $a_n$ is the sequence
$$ 1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\dots $$
and $b_n$ is the sequence
$$ \frac{1}{4},1,\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{9},\dots$$

Then $A=B$ so $|A-B|=0$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n-b_n|>0$.

It is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n-b_n|$ converges, but the easiest proof is to note that $|a_n-b_n|\leq a_n+b_n$, so this gets you right back to $A+B$ anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I've just noticed this, which I've added as a comment. Cheers.

Comment: Your observation $\max[a_n,b_n] = \frac{1}{2}[a_n + b_n + |a_n-b_n|]$ is interesting but also seems more complex than the observation $\max[a_n,b_n] \leq |a_n| + |b_n|$.